# Can't approve a workflow task after the initiator was removed from Active Directory

Tags: workflow, active-directory, tasks

We have a rare but frustrating issue in which a workflow and task are initiated by someone who then is later removed from AD. These tasks can no longer be actioned by the assignee or anyone else for that matter. Anyone aware of a workaround for this rather than restarting the workflow?